# AVG Internet Security 2014 gets stuck at 99% during scan

Tags: windows-7, avg-antivirus

I run a scan every night with AVG and in the morning I notice that lately it has been getting stuck at 99%. I can't stop or pause the scan, I have to restart my computer. It doesn't seem to keep getting stuck on the same file, so I can't just delete that specific file.

My scan preferences are set to only scan my main drive, and my scanning speed is set to fast. Any idea on what's wrong and what I can do?

Comment: More then likely your hdd is failing and its unable to scan a file, see what file its stuck on, and delete it

Comment: @Ramhound As stated in my question, it doesn't keep getting stuck on the same file, its different everytime.

Comment: Feel free to confirm it.  Switch the locations of the card. If the setup stays the same you have your answer.